# TSQL: Get the last user for each case ...one record x user only

Tags: sql, t-sql

**SCENARIO:**
Imagine a TABLE like this:

```
Auto_INC, UserID_FK, CaseID_FK,    Date
   idX      userX      caseX
```

and when it is filled, it looks like this:

```
   id1,     user4,     case20,   2010/01/12  
   id2,     user1,     case13,   2010/03/20  
   id3,     user2,     case10,   2010/03/22  
   id4,     user1,     case21,   2011/01/10  
   id5,     user2,      case9,   2011/01/11  
   id6,     user3,     case20,   2011/02/01  
   id7,     user1,      case9,   2011/03/25
```

**QUESTION:**
How do i get ONE CASE Record with the LAST User Assigned ??

So if one user has been assigned, it will automatically override all previous users on that case.

Something like this:

```
   id7,     user1,      case9,   2011/03/25  
   id2,     user1,     case13,   2010/03/20  
   id4,     user1,     case21,   2011/01/10
   id6,     user3,     case20,   2011/02/01    
   id3,     user2,     case10,   2010/03/22
```

In this case User1 has been assigned to 3 cases, User2 to 2 cases but one was overridden by User1, User3 had 1 case and it did override User4 ...so User4 does not get any case ..therefore it will NOT appear on the list.

**NOTE BENE**
Ideally we should be getting as result ..as many records as there are CASES on the original table !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
declare @T table
(
  Auto_INC int identity primary key, 
  UserID_FK int, 
  CaseID_FK int,
  [Date] date
);

insert into @T values
(4, 20, '2010/01/12'),
(1, 13, '2010/03/20'),
(2, 10, '2010/03/22'),
(1, 21, '2010/01/10'),
(2, 9,  '2010/01/11'),
(3, 20, '2010/02/01'),
(1, 9,  '2010/03/25');

with C as
(
  select *,
         row_number() over(partition by CaseID_FK 
                           order by [Date] desc) as rn
  from @T
)
select Auto_INC, UserID_FK, CaseID_FK, [Date]
from C
where rn = 1;
```

Result:

```
Auto_INC    UserID_FK   CaseID_FK   Date
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------
7           1           9           2010-03-25
3           2           10          2010-03-22
2           1           13          2010-03-20
6           3           20          2010-02-01
4           1           21          2010-01-10
```

Comment: I had to edit my initial post, cause it was not clear that I need to get as many records as there are CASES ...with this SQL i'm getting as many records as ...USERS.

Comment: This is the correct syntax and result. The question was changed so this result is not correct anymore

Comment: I agree...this answer was returning the right result but the problem resided on my side where i did express wrongly the question.

Comment: @Filu, Updated answer. Not as complicated any more with your changed requirement.

Comment: Funny enough ...the right answer is both the previous one and this current one. Amazing the power of SQL but even more amazing the knowledge you have with TSQL :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do a sub-query on the same table to get the latest user (and the date for that user).

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.CaseID_FK, (SELECT TOP 1 T2.UserID_FK
        FROM Table AS T2
        WHERE T2.CaseID_FK = T1.CaseID_FK
        ORDER BY T2.Date DESC) AS User,
    (SELECT TOP 1 T2.Date
        FROM Table AS T2
        WHERE T2.CaseID_FK = T1.CaseID_FK
        ORDER BY T2.Date DESC) AS Date,
FROM Table AS T1
```

EDIT:

This should limit to returning only the number of rows as you have cases.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT T1.CaseID_FK, MAX(T1.Date) AS Date
    FROM Table AS T1
    GROUP BY CaseID_FK) AS T2 LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT *
    FROM Table AS T3) AS T4 ON T2.CaseID_FK = T4.CaseID_FK AND T2.Date = T4.Date
```

Comment: I have updated the initial post because it was not to clear. With this query, if the original table has 1000 records, I'm getting 1000 records result set.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE T WHERE
(T.CASEID_FK, T.Auto_INC) IN
(
SELECT A.CASEID_FK, MAX (A.Auto_INC) MI FROM TABLE A
INNER JOIN (SELECT X.CASEID_FK, MAX (X.DATE) MD FROM TABLE X GROUP BY X.CASEID_FK) Y ON A.DATE = Y.MD AND A.CASEID_FK = Y.CASEID_FK
GROUP BY A.CASEID_FK
)
```